# Hibernate Spring Joins

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two tables with primary key as emp_id. I'm using Spring,Hibernate,MVC.

domain files:

```
public class Employee_Domain {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer emp_id;
private String domain_name;

@OneToOne @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Employee empDomObj;
    @Id
@Column(name = "EMP_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getEmp_id() {
    return emp_id;
}

public void setEmp_id(Integer emp_id) {
    this.emp_id = emp_id;
}

@Column(name = "DOMAIN_NAME", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 200)
public String getDomain_name() {
    return domain_name;
}

public void setDomain_name(String domain_name) {
    this.domain_name = domain_name;
}
     }
```

and

```
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer emp_id;
private String emp_name;
private String emp_role;

@OneToOne @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Employee_Domain empDomObj;


@Id
@Column(name = "EMP_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getEmp_id() {
    return emp_id;
}

public void setEmp_id(Integer emp_id) {
    this.emp_id = emp_id;
}

@Column(name = "EMP_NAME", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 500)
public String getEmp_name() {
    return emp_name;
}

public void setEmp_name(String emp_name) {
    this.emp_name = emp_name;
}

@Column(name = "ROLE", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
public String getEmp_role() {
    return emp_role;
}

public void setEmp_role(String emp_role) {
    this.emp_role = emp_role;
}
```

my domainDao Implementation is like:

```
@Override
public List<Employee_Domain> findEmployeeByDomain1(String domain_name) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Employee_Domain.class);
    criteria.setFetchMode("EMP_DETAILS", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("domain_name", domain_name));
    return criteria.list();
}
```

and using MVC im calling this function and passing the object to jsp to print it.

Executing this brings a simple SQL query:

```
select this_.EMP_ID as EMP1_3_0_, this_.DOMAIN_NAME as DOMAIN2_3_0_ from EMPLOYEE_DOMAIN_MAPPING this_ where this_.DOMAIN_NAME=?
```

why there is no joins happening? what am i missing? Im new to all this, so please dont hammer me. I tried searching a lot for similar examples but didnt get.

Answer (score 0):

The tables will be joined if their relationship is **one-to-many**.

In your domain files, the relationship between **Employee_Domain** and **Employee** is **one-to-one**.

Try to change it to:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="Employee_Domain")
private List<Employee> employees= new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

And the join will happen.